# regex returns true but?

Tags: regex, typescript, zod

I have date field as YYYYMMDD, it's definition:

```
zod.string().max(8).regex(new RegExp('^(19[0-9][0-9]|20[0-9][0-9]|[0-1][0-9]{3})(1[0-2]|0[1-9])(3[01]|[0-2][1-9]|[12]0)$'));
```

and value 20001915

I mean it's definition is ok, test in online checker  ([https://www.regextester.com/[enter](https://www.regextester.com/%5Benter) link description here][1](https://www.regextester.com/)) tell me FALSE (month number is false - 19) but zod passes this value as correct, WHY?

Comment: there are only `12` months in a year, so a month number of `19` is not valid and the reason why Zod passes the value `20001915` as correct is because Zod's regex validation is not strict by default and it allows for partial matches, meaning it only checks if the input string contains a substring that matches the regular expression pattern.in your case, the substring `200019` matches the pattern, so Zod considers it a valid value!

Answer (score 1):

As some one said in the comment, the regular expression is correct. But, it's important to note that while zod regular expression checks the format, it doesn't validate the date itself for correctness in terms of real-world dates. In your example, the value "20001915" has the correct format (YYYYMMDD), but it represents the 19th month, which doesn't exist, hence the external online checker correctly identifies it as FALSE.

So you need to validate the date separately like below:

```
const dateString = "20001915";
const year = parseInt(dateString.substring(0, 4));
const month = parseInt(dateString.substring(4, 6)) - 1; // Months are 0-indexed
const day = parseInt(dateString.substring(6, 8));

const date = new Date(year, month, day);

if (
  date.getFullYear() === year &&
  date.getMonth() === month &&
  date.getDate() === day
) {
  console.log("Valid date.");
} else {
  console.log("Invalid date.");
}
```

And additionally you can optimise the regex like this:

```
^(19\d\d|20\d\d)(0[1-9]|1[0-2])(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])$
```